# Delete Attribute of Xml node c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ua="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd">
  <ServerConfiguration>
    <SecurityPolicies>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>None_1</SecurityMode>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
    </SecurityPolicies>
  </ServerConfiguration>
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

What I want is to add more node named ServerSecurityPolicy by code.
Then I use this code:

```
            string docaddress = "D:\\abc.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(docaddress);
            var root = doc.Root;
            var these = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "SecurityPolicies");
            XElement addelement = new XElement("ServerSecurityPolicy");
            addelement.Add(new XElement("SecurityMode", "None_1"));           
            foreach (var elem in these)
            {
                elem.Add(addelement);
            }
            doc.Save(docaddress);
```

It actually works, but the newly added node is something like this:

```
      <ServerSecurityPolicy xmlns="">
        <SecurityMode>None_1</SecurityMode>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
```

I don't want the attribute "xmlns", then I try to delete it by something like this:

```
            var these2 = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "ServerSecurityPolicy");
            foreach (var elem in these2)
            {
                    label2.Text += elem.Attribute("xmlns").Name.LocalName;
                    elem.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();
            }
```

The label2.Text shows "xmlnsxmlnsxmlsn..." so that I think the elem.Attribute("xmlns") has pointed to the attributes I want to delete, but the Remove() not work.
Can you suggest me some ways to delete the attribute or add node without attribute?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your sample code doesn't compile, and having changed it to `elem.Add(addelement);` so that it *will* compile, the new node does *not* have `xmlns=""` in - using the XML file you've shown us. I suspect that's because you've only shown us *part* of the document, and the part you've omitted has set a root namespace. If you can provide a [mcve], it will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Hi  Jon Skeet, thank you for replying. Firstly, you're right, I named the XElement "ro", but when post thread here, I think I should use something easier to observe, but I forget to change that last line. Secondly, because the xml file is quite long, so I just focus on some nodes to shorten and simplize the question, but from your answer, the error seems to be somewhere else. Can you help me to check the full xml file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uO9nXAEBMOwCivV9VM9Nf1rQSl2Pn9fk/view?usp=sharing Here's the xml file.

Comment: No, please don't just put it on Drive - please provide a [mcve] *in the question*. (The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. Someone else looking at your question in the future should be able to understand whether your question relates to theirs.) We don't need the *actual* full document - but we do need *a* full document that demonstrates the problem, along with code to reproduce the problem. Please edit the question to fix both the code (ideally turning it into a genuine complete console app ready to copy/paste) and the doc.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, thank you for specifing me how to work with Stack Overflow. I'm not sure about the console app, but I have edited my question as what I understand (and checked the code). Can you help me to re-check my problem? A few more detail, as you said before, I have check the root, and I think those attributes of it (<ApplicationConfiguration>) create the xmlns attribute of my new nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element you want to create is actually in the `http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd` namespace, which is the default for the  document because of this part of the root element:

```xml
xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd"
```

You can create an element in that namespace easily:

```cs
XNamespace configNs = "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd";
var these = root.Descendants(configNs + "ServerSecurityPolicy");
```

When you add *that* to your document, you'll find it won't add the `xmlns=""` part, which was present because you were adding an element without a namespace.

I'd also suggest using the namespace to find elements too:

```cs
XNamespace configNs = "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd";
var these = root.Descendants(configNs + "SecurityPolicies");
```

That's much cleaner than just using the local name, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an empty attribute - which `xmlns=""` refers to - is because your document's root node belongs to the namespace `xsi`. When you're adding a node without a namespace - as you're doing in your example - you're not actually binding it to the `xsi` namespace.

To make your node part of the root namespace, replace

```
new XElement("ServerSecurityPolicy")
```

with

```
new XElement("ServerSecurityPolicy",
              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
```

Comment: Hi @silkfire, I'm not sure about the namespace, but I think my root node share 2 namespaces (`xsi` and `ua`), right? So I try to add another XAttribute for the `ua` namespace. The problem is, the newly created nodes now have 3 different attributes, the `xsi` and `ua` are same as root node, and the `xmlns=""` (empty attribute). Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: @halaMurak: No, it's about the *default* namespace, which is `http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd`

Comment: The document *doesn't* belong to the namespace with the alias xsi. It belongs to the `http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd` namespace. The OP should create a new element in that namespace - there's no need to manually create an `xmlns` attribute as part of it. (See my answer, basically.)