# Remove Element from xml file with c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

recently I have a question in this thread: [Delete Attribute of Xml node c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253317/delete-attribute-of-xml-node-c-sharp)
Again, I'm struggling with modifying the xml file.
Here's the xml:

```
<ApplicationConfiguration>
  <ServerConfiguration>
    <SecurityPolicies>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>None_1</SecurityMode>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>None_2</SecurityMode>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
    </SecurityPolicies>
  </ServerConfiguration>
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

What I want is to remove all ServerSecurityPolicy nodes, so the result will be:

```
<ApplicationConfiguration>
  <ServerConfiguration>
    <SecurityPolicies>
    </SecurityPolicies>
  </ServerConfiguration>
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

Then I use this code:

```
            string docaddress = "D:\\abc.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(docaddress);
            var root = doc.Root;
            var these = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "ServerSecurityPolicy");        
            foreach (var elem in these)
            {
                elem.Remove();
            }
            doc.Save(docaddress);
```

Here's the problem:

- When the code inside foreach is `elem.Remove()`, it returns an error like: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
- When the code inside foreach is `label1.Text=elem.Name.LocalName`, the `label1` displays `ServerSecurityPolicy`. So that the `elem.Name.LocalName` works normally, but the `elem.Remove()` does not?
- I have tried `elem.RemoveNodes()`. Based on the void description, I think the code will delete all child nodes (the SecurityMode nodes), but it doesn't work (no error, but just cannot delete anything). Same with `elem.RemoveAll()`.
  Can you tell me if I have done anything wrong? Thank you

Comment: As you're not simply removing items from the collection you're looping over, I'm not sure if "use a for loop" will work.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again. I have solve it by replace the line
`var these = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "ServerSecurityPolicy");`
with
`var these = root.Descendants("SecurityPolicies");`
then `RemoveAll()`

Answer (score 0):

> This code will help to get your expected output

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlpath = "sample.xml";

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);

        var list = xdoc.Elements().Descendants().ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.Descendants("ServerSecurityPolicy").Remove();
        }

        xdoc.Save(xmlpath);
    }
```